# song length countdown, need to keep track of remaining length

Tags: php, javascript, countdown

I have the javascript below for a song length countdown. I use that in a php page.

The problem I have, is that when I refresh the page, or when I go into the page while the song is playing, I won't get the remaining length. I'll get the full song lentgh countdown.

For example, for a 2 minutes song. If it starts at 9:38 AM, and I go into the page at 9:39 AM, I want a 1 minute countdown, not 2 minutes.

So I guess the real question is : how can I keep track, on the server side, of the remaining song length ?

```
var startTime, countAmt, interval;
function now() {
  return ((new Date()).getTime());
}
function tick() {
  var elapsed = now() - startTime;
  var cnt = countAmt - elapsed;
  var elem = document.getElementById("countdown");
  if (cnt > 0) {
    elem.innerHTML = minute(Math.round(cnt / 1000));
  } else {
    elem.innerHTML = "0:00";
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
function startTimer(secs) {
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = minute(secs);
  countAmt = secs * 1000;
  startTime = now();
  interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);  
}
function minute(secs){
    minVar = Math.floor(secs/60);  // The minutes
    secs = secs % 60;              // The balance of seconds
    if (secs < 10) {
        secs = "0"+secs;
    }
    return minVar+":"+secs;
}
startTimer(<?php echo $stream['info']['length'];?>);
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = minute(<?php echo $stream['info']['length'];?>);
```

Comment: Create a server side page which gets the POST,GET data and stores that value to either session or database,
Make a ajax call to that server page using timer on every second. 

When the page refreshes pull the data for session or database wherever you stored you data.

Comment: Thanks prabeen giri, but unfortunately I have no idea how I could do that. If song length is 2 minutes, the ajax will always return 2 minutes when page refreshes. What do you propose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Winamp's advanced title formatting I could send the time when the song begins in this format: `h:m:s`.

I'm getting the total seconds:

```
sscanf($song_begins, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
$song_begins_sec = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
```

Get current time:

```
$now = date('H:i:s', time());
```

In seconds:

```
sscanf($now, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
$now_sec = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
```

I then calcute when the song ends:

```
$songend = $song_begins_sec+$stream['info']['length'];
```

So the right $countdown is:

```
$countdown = $songend-$now_sec;
```